# The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict

Tags: botframework

While trying to register a bot in Microsoft Bot Framework, I am getting the following error message :
The remote server returned an error: (409) Conflict.

The messaging endpoint is of the form :
https://your_bots_hostname/api/messages

The bot is hosted in azure.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I got the same Error during the registration of a bot in Microsoft Bot Framework. Mostly the above error occurs whenever we are trying to create a new bot, in that registration we are specified the Existing Microsoft Application Id in the Microsoft Application Id field of bot registration form.

So, try to create new Microsoft Application with new name (like that the name would never use before) for your new bot then your issue resolve.

-Hope it will be help to you.

-Kishore